# Recursion behaving strangely with Reflection

Tags: java, reflection, recursion

I have the following structure of a java function:

```
public void recursiveFun(Object currentReturnValue, int numRecursiveCalls) {

for(Method currentMethod: currentReturnValue.getClass().getMethods()) {
    String methodName = currentMethod.getName();
    // base case
    if(methodName.equals("getObject")) {
        Object retVal = currentMethod.invoke(currentReturnValue, null);
        System.out.println(retVal);
        return;
    }
    else {
        numRecursiveCalls++;
        currentReturnValue = currentMethod.invoke(currentReturnValue, null);
        recursiveFun(currentReturnValue, numRecursiveCalls);
        boolean previousFrame = true;
    }
 }
```

I set 2 breakpoints, one in the base case and the second at previousFrame=true.  It first stops in my base case, and I keep stepping over.  I find it does go back to the previous frame because it sets previousFrame to true, but the type of currentReturnValue remained the same!  It should be a different type.

For example, the Location class has a getIdNum() that returns an object of type MyInteger.  MyInteger has a getObject() method that returns an object.  In my case case the return statement should have popped off the frame with currentReturnValue being a MyInteger and went back to the frame where currentReturnValue is  a Location.

Comment: Suggestion: use a logging mechanism or at least System.out.println() to dump out what is going on in sequence.  Part of the problem might be just your debugger confusing you.

Answer (score 1):

The point is that you can not change `currentReturnValue` that way. Even though `currentReturnValue` is a reference to an object, that reference is passed by value. That means that you can not change which object `currentReturnValue` points to so that the change becomes visible in the "parent call".

If you were able to pass the reference by reference, that would work (like an `out` parameter in C#, for example). Then you could change the object that `currentReturnValue` references and it would also change in the parent call.

Usually you'd make your method return the new return value instead of trying to output it through a parameter.